# Insight Micro ORM throws exception on Bulk Copy

Tags: .net, orm

I am doing a bulk insert to sql server 2008 R2 database using Insight micro ORM.I get this exception when i execute the bulk insert.I have no clue why this is happening.I made sure that the property name and the sql server table column names are the correct type and the name

This is the C# code

```
Public static void DoBulkInsert(string permissionName)
{

using (IToolTransaction tran = Connection.OpenWithTransactionAs<IToolTransaction>())
                  {
                  List<AuditRemovePermisison> audList = new List<AuditRemovePermisison>();
                  list<int> userIds = getUserIds();
                  foreach(int userId in userIds)
                  {
                    audList.Add(new AuditRemovePermisison
                  {
                     ToolId = null,                     
                     UserId = userId,
                     Name = permissionName,
                     CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
                  });
                  }
                      tran.UsersDeactivateByPermissionName
                      tran.BulkCopy("RJ.AuditRemovePermission", audList, configure: (InsightBulkCopy bulk) =>
                          {
                              bulk.BatchSize = 5000;
                          },transaction:tran);                      
                      tran.Commit();
                  }
}
```

and POCO is

```
public  class AuditRemovePermisison
    {

        public int? ToolId { get; set; }        
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

[Sql(Schema = "RJ")]
   public interface IToolTransaction : IDbConnection,IDbTransaction
    {
           void UsersDeactivateByPermissionName(string PermissionName);
    }

```
Unable to cast object of type 'IToolTransaction1c270692-c6ed-4c04-a8ba-e06109c3c3fd' to type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection'.

System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'IToolTransaction526ca86c-f1e4-4552-80a6-798a2a36d69e' to type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbConnection'.
  Source=Insight.Database.Providers.Glimpse
  StackTrace:
       at Insight.Database.Providers.Glimpse.GlimpseInsightDbProvider.GetInnerConnection(IDbConnection connection) in c:\projects.net\Insight\Insight.Database\Insight.Database.Providers.Glimpse\GlimpseInsightDbProvider.cs:line 58
       at Insight.Database.Providers.WrappedInsightDbProvider.GetSupportedBulkCopyOptions(IDbConnection connection) in c:\projects.net\Insight\Insight.Database\Insight.Database\Providers\WrappedInsightDbProvider.cs:line 82
       at Insight.Database.Providers.DbConnectionWrapperInsightDbProvider.GetSupportedBulkCopyOptions(IDbConnection connection) in c:\projects.net\Insight\Insight.Database\Insight.Database\Providers\DbConnectionWrapperInsightDbProvider.cs:line 41
       at Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.BulkCopy(IDbConnection connection, String tableName, IDataReader source, Action`1 configure, Boolean closeConnection, InsightBulkCopyOptions options, IDbTransaction transaction) in c:\projects.net\Insight\Insight.Database\Insight.Database\Extensions\DBConnectionExtensions.cs:line 1380
       at Insight.Database.DBConnectionExtensions.BulkCopy[T](IDbConnection connection, String tableName, IEnumerable`1 list, Action`1 configure, Boolean closeConnection, InsightBulkCopyOptions options, IDbTransaction transaction) in c:\projects.net\Insight\Insight.Database\Insight.Database\Extensions\DBConnectionExtensions.cs:line 1339
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with double-wrapping the connection in both a Glimpse wrapper and an auto-generated interface.

I've opened a github issue to track this:

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/issues/158

In the meantime, it should work if you turn off glimpse profiling for that scenario. I don't think it can profile bulk copies anyway.